# Formik + Yup Field array - Deep Fields Validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

I have two formik form components, One is basic, That basic form has two fields, Holiday Title and Year and that basic form contains field array which contain a field array, and I am using react, Trying to validate it all together.

Everything works fine, But I want to try if a year is not selected then the date field in formik fieldarray should display an error that "selects the year first" and if a year is selected then it should be referred to date field(It's own)[image]s validation, Anyone can help?

```
validationSchema={Yup.object({
        title: Yup.string().required("Name is require"),
        year: Yup.string().required('Select Year,Date Option is Disabled'),
        holidays: Yup.array().of(
        Yup.object().shape({
                 name: Yup.string().required("Name required"),
                 date: Yup.string().when(['year', 'holidays'], {
                 is: (year) => year==="",
                 then: Yup.string().required('Select Year First'),
                 otherwise: Yup.string().required('Field is required')
                 }),
               })
             )},['year', 'holidays'])}
```

PS:  The date picker( Textfield, type='date' Material UI V4.12) will be disabled until yearfield is, This how I am currently managing

Comment: `is: (year) => console.log(Yup.object()),` not correct, you must return boolean value. `is: (year) => {
   console.log(Yup.object());
   return Boolean(year)
},`

Comment: I tried it, but i forgot to change that line, I was able manage it by using useState and custome validation, By the way, thanks for pointing out.